# access https cloud function end point via android retrofit

Tags: android, google-cloud-functions, retrofit2

I am trying to get a response from a cloud function, using retrofit in Android.

I do not know if it is important to mention, but inside **functions/index.js** there are other functions besides that shown below.

Below is how I wrote my cloud function end point:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

app.post('/shipping', (req, res) => {
  console.log('Inside https request for shipping')
  res.status(200).send('Helo from express post');
})

exports.shipping = functions.https.onRequest(app);
```

And below is how I call the end point from Android:

**FirebaseApi**

```
public interface FirebaseApi {
    @POST("shipping")
    Call<String> getShippingPrice();
}
```

And the request:

```
private void sendRequestToFirebaseCloudFunctions() {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://us-central1-<your-project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        FirebaseApi firebaseApi = retrofit.create(FirebaseApi.class);
        Call<String> call = firebaseApi.getShippingPrice();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: isSuccessful "+response.isSuccessful());
                Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: body: "+response.body());
                Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: errorBody: "+response.errorBody());
                try {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: error: "+response.errorBody().string());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onResponse: catherror: "+e.getMessage());

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i(TAG, "onFailure: "+t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
```

The Logs are shown below:

```
onResponse: isSuccessful false
onResponse: body: null
onResponse: errorBody: okhttp3.ResponseBody$1@3e75b8d
onResponse: error: <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Error</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <pre>Cannot POST /</pre>
    </body>
    </html>
```

How can I get it to work?

I've seen some tutorials adding CORS. Do I really need CORS even if my app is connected to firebase and using firestore and realtime database?

I appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current code,  the correct path to POST to would be:

```
https://us-central1-<your-project-id>.cloudfunctions.net/shipping/shipping
```

This is because you export your function as `shipping`, but also only listen to POST requests on the relative path `/shipping`

Comment: It worket in postman, but not in Android. `onFailure: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 1 path $`

Comment: @AlitonOliveira You currently send back plain text, not JSON. If you want to send JSON, use `res.status(200).json('Helo from express post')`

Comment: It worked. Last question: how do I create a path to be just `/shipping` instead of `/shipping/shipping`?

Comment: Use just `app.post('/', ...)` instead or host it behind Firebase Hosting. You could then use something like `api.your domain.com` instead of the cloud functions URL.